# VS 2022 - Publish to folder programmatically

Tags: asp.net-core, publish

Is there any way to publish a .Net Core web app to a folder programmatically?

Comment: You can run [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish), either manually, from a script, or even from C# if that is what you mean.